# g++ C++0x enum class Compiler Warnings

Tags: c++, g++, c++11, compiler-warnings

I've been refactoring my horrible mess of C++ type-safe psuedo-enums to the new C++0x type-safe enums because they're *way* more readable.  Anyway, I use them in exported classes, so I explicitly mark them to be exported:

```
enum class  __attribute__((visibility("default"))) MyEnum : unsigned int
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
};
```

Compiling this with g++ yields the following warning:

> type attributes ignored after type is already defined

This seems very strange, since, as far as I know, that warning is meant to prevent actual mistakes like:

```
class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) MyClass { };
class __attribute__((visibility("hidden")))  MyClass;
```

Of course, I'm clearly not doing that, since I have only marked the visibility attributes at the definition of the `enum class` and I'm not re-defining or declaring it anywhere else (I can duplicate this error with a single file).

Ultimately, I can't make this bit of code actually cause a problem, save for the fact that, if I change a value and re-compile the consumer without re-compiling the shared library, the consumer passes the new values and the shared library has no idea what to do with them (although I wouldn't expect that to work in the first place).

Am I being way too pedantic?  Can this be safely ignored?  I suspect so, but at the same time, having this error prevents me from compiling with `Werror`, which makes me uncomfortable.  I would really like to see this problem go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the `-Wno-attributes` flag to turn the warning off.

(It's probably a bug in gcc?)

Comment: I reported the bug to GCC's Bugzilla.

Comment: @TravisGockel: Could you please point me to that ticket? I've posted a workaround below.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43407

Answer (score 5):

It works for me with g++ 4.8.2 the following way:

```
enum class MyEnum : unsigned int
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
};
```

(change the position of the `attribute` declaration)