# Can I use gcc visibility attributes on an enumeration?

Tags: gcc, g++

I have the following enum:

```
__atttribute__((visibility ("default") )) enum MSG
{
    OK,
    FAIL,
};
```

When I compile, it gives me the warning:

```
warning: attribute ignored in declaration of ‘enum MSG’
warning: attribute for ‘enum MSG’ must follow the ‘enum’ keyword
```

When I put the attribute *after* the enum, I get the following errors:

```
warning: type attributes are honored only at type definition
error: use of enum ‘MSG’ without previous declaration
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Could you include the actual source code snippet? It makes no sense to change visibility of an enumeration *type*. It's not a symbol (such as a function or a variable).

Comment: here is my enum definition:

`__attribute__ ((visibility ("default") )) enum MSG
{
OK,
FAIL,
};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visibility attribute applies to *symbols* like functions and variables. A definition of an enumeration *type* that doesn't contain a variable name doesn't create any symbols.

Enumeration type without a variable:

```
enum msg { OK, FAIL };
```

An enumeration variable:

```
enum msg message;
```

Enumeration type together with a variable:

```
enum msg { OK, FAIL } message;
```

In the first case, there's no symbol the visibility attribute could affect at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by declaring the type of your enum like this:

```
enum class MSG : std::uint32_t __atttribute__((visibility ("default") ))
{
    OK,
    FAIL,
};
```

Though it seems like this is a bug in GCC that was fixed in versions 6+.  [Related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463113/g-c0x-enum-class-compiler-warnings)